# setFormula statement producing Parse Error

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been trying to make some changes to an inherited spreadsheet and being new to Google Script I'm struggling. I am trying to set a formula in a cell and i've added other lines that seem to work fine but I'm at a loss with this one.

I've managed to get the below to work but don't want absolute references.

```
targetSheet.getRange(startRow + 1, 4, 1, 1).setFormula('=IF(C5 < G5, \"S\",IF(C5 > I5,\"VC\",\"C\"))');
```

The below code is what I was hoping to move to so that it is more dynamic.

```
targetSheet.getRange(startRow + 2, 4, 1, 1).setFormulaR1C1("=IF(R[0]C[-1] < R[0]C[+3], \"S\", IF(R[0]C[-1] > R[0]C[+5], \"VC\" , \"C\"))");
```

However, the above simply produces a Formula Parse Error. 
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using R1C1 notation for extending Sheets, you don't need the superfluous `+` if the cell you're targetting has a larger row or column value. You can fix this formula just by removing these:

```
var range = targetSheet.getRange(startRow + 2, 4, 1, 1);
range.setFormulaR1C1('=IF(R[0]C[-1] < R[0]C[3], "S", IF(R[0]C[-1] > R[0]C[5], "VC" , "C"))');
```

You can also avoid having to specify backslashes to escape the extra double quotes by using single quotes around the whole formula in `setFormulaR1C1()`.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I like the structure of that better than what I had tried to copy from elsewhere. And it works well having made the adjustment! Thanks.